# pymongo - how to find primary from a rep set

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I will have a list of ip address where mongo replicates are running.  I will need to automate adding a node.  How can I issue a status command or another method to find out which IP is the primary using pymongo?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [ReplicaSetConnetion](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/replica_set_connection.html#pymongo.replica_set_connection.ReplicaSetConnection) to connect to your replica set. And according to the documentation for [High Availability and PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/high_availability.html#replicasetconnection)

> By default an instance of ReplicaSetConnection will only send queries to the primary member of the replica set. To use secondaries for queries we have to change the ReadPreference